# Resources In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, resources

i have about 400 pages and UserControls in my asp.net website.
what is the best way for keeping strings on resource file?
its difficult to manage 500 local resource files and and difficult to put all strings on global resource file.
what is the solution?
Help Me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource (.resx) file. You can separate resource files by their type. One each for Messages, Error codes messages etc.